# TikZ automate numbered box-form

Tags: tikz-pgf, box

I am creating a numbered box-form for limited-word writing exercise where one unit represents one character. Each unit has an upper box and lower box. The upper box will house the character, and the lower box will house a number that represents the character. One unit looks like this:
[image: One unit has an upper box and lower box.]

Currently the form's character limit is 80 characters. So far I have made 12 boxes manually and it turns out to be tedious. This is what the ouput looks like at 100% zoom:
[image: Part of the numbered box-form.]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{box_upper}=[rectangle, draw, anchor=south, text centered, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=8mm]%

\tikzstyle{box_lower}=[rectangle, draw, anchor=north west, text centered, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=4mm]%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[box_lower] (a) at (0,0) {1}; 
\node[box_upper] (x1) at (a.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (b) at (a.north east) {2};
\node[box_upper] (x2) at (b.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (c) at (b.north east) {3};
\node[box_upper] (x3) at (c.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (d) at (c.north east) {4};
\node[box_upper] (x4) at (d.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (e) at (d.north east) {5};
\node[box_upper] (x5) at (e.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (f) at (e.north east) {6};
\node[box_upper] (x6) at (f.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (g) at (f.north east) {7};
\node[box_upper] (x7) at (g.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (h) at (g.north east) {8};
\node[box_upper] (x8) at (h.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (i) at (h.north east) {9};
\node[box_upper] (x9) at (i.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (j) at (i.north east) {10};
\node[box_upper] (x10) at (j.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (k) at (0,-2) {11};
\node[box_upper] (x11) at (k.north) {};
%
\node[box_lower] (l) at (k.north east) {12};
\node[box_upper] (x12) at (l.north) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. Out of curiosity, is this the right way to do this? Are there any other ways to achieve the same result?
2. Can anyone kindly make an automated version where the rows break after every 20th box? Is it possible?
3. In the future I plan to re-use this box-form as a handwriting exercise sheet by:

   a. Enlarging the upper boxes' width and height.

   b. Increasing the character limit, say to 300 characters.

   c. Breaking rows after the 10th box.

   Can these changeables also be included in the automated version if possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use loops.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\totalbox{80}
  \def\breakat{20}
  \def\boxheight{.7cm}
  \def\boxwidth{.7cm}
  \def\numheight{.4cm}
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={
      inner sep=0pt,draw,minimum height=\boxheight,
      minimum width=\boxwidth
    },
    num/.style={
      draw,font=\sffamily\scriptsize,minimum width=\boxwidth,
      inner sep=0pt,minimum height=\numheight
    }
  }
  \foreach \i [parse=true] in {1,...,\totalbox/\breakat} {% thanks to Schrodinger's cat!
    \coordinate (\i-0) at (0,-\i*\boxheight*2.2);
    \foreach \j [count=\k from 0] in {1,...,\breakat} {
      \path (\i-\k.east) node[right,box] (\i-\j) {};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\output{\breakat*(\i-1)+\j}
      \path (\i-\j.south) node[below,num] {\output};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer to your questions:

1. No. Using loops (`pgffor`) is the right way IMHO.
2. Well, see above. It is automated.
3. Change the values of `\totalbox`, `\breakat`, `\boxheight`, `\boxwidth` and `\numwidth` to see changes.

Some notes:

1. DON'T use `\tikzstyle`. It is deprecated. Use `\tikzset` instead, as I did in the code above.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that you need `[parse=true]` on an up-to-date LaTeX installation: `\foreach \i [parse=true] in {1,...,\totalbox/\breakat}` since otherwise there will be an error.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, fixed my answer! Am using an outdated portable installation (not having access to my main device), so there are no errors :)

Comment: You're welcome! (I was guessing something like this happened.) +1.

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer but I get 5 errors when compiling. Can you fix it so that I can accept it?

Comment: @GulaKapas What is the error message? Is your TeX distribution up to date? On my TeX distribution (TeX Live 2019, updated today), it runs fine.

Comment: @GulaKapas If you are using Overleaf, remove `[parse=true]` (I advise against doing so, though).

Comment: I get the errors: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted), Missing = inserted for \ifdim, Missing number, treated as zero. I'm using Kile version 2.9.91 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @GulaKapas What is the first line of your log file?

Comment: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)

Comment: @GulaKapas So you are using TeX Live 2017, which is _very_ outdated. Please update your distribution. LaTeX is very actively developed, so in 2 years the change is very considerable.

Answer (score 6):

Conceptually similar to [Fractal's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/203621/fractal) in that it uses loops. Here it is one loop and using `mod`. This defines a pic that allows you to set the number `n` of boxes and the number `pr` of boxes per row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{box_upper/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=south, text centered, minimum
width=8mm, minimum height=8mm},
box_lower/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=north west, text centered, minimum
width=8mm, minimum height=4mm},
pics/numbered box/.style={code={
\tikzset{numbered box/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/numbered box/##1}} 
\foreach \X in {1,...,\pv{n}}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{Mod(\X,\pv{pr})}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{-2*int((\X-1)/\pv{pr})}
\ifnum\Z=1
\node[box_lower] (y\X) at (0,\Y) {\X}; 
\else
\node[box_lower] (y\X) at (y\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.north east) {\X};
\fi
\node[box_upper] (x\X) at (y\X.north) {};}}},
numbered box/.cd,n/.initial=20,pr/.initial=10
}%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic{numbered box={n=30,pr=18}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic{numbered box={n=50,pr=15}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want 20 boxes per row you need either to make the page wider or the boxes smaller in order to avoid an overfull hbox warning.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{box_upper/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=south, text centered, minimum
width=8mm, minimum height=8mm},
box_lower/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=north west, text centered, minimum
width=8mm, minimum height=4mm},
pics/numbered box/.style={code={
\tikzset{numbered box/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/numbered box/##1}} 
\foreach \X in {1,...,\pv{n}}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{Mod(\X,\pv{pr})}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{-2*int((\X-1)/\pv{pr})}
\ifnum\Z=1
\node[box_lower] (y\X) at (0,\Y) {\X}; 
\else
\node[box_lower] (y\X) at (y\the\numexpr\X-1\relax.north east) {\X};
\fi
\node[box_upper] (x\X) at (y\X.north) {};}}},
numbered box/.cd,n/.initial=20,pr/.initial=10
}%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,transform shape]
\pic{numbered box={n=30,pr=20}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]